# Restrict executer and driver, memory and core parameter in spark-submit on spark only cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

We have a spark only cluster for multiple users, in spark-default.conf have below property set

`spark.driver.memory 2g` 
`spark.executor.cores 1` 
`spark.executor.memory 2g`

As we have a multiple users, i dont want users to pass below parameters in spark-submit command as this can utilise complete cluster resources.

`--driver-memory 5g` 
`--executor-cores 5` 
`--executor-memory 5g`

is that any possible way to restrict passing above runtime value in spark-submit command ?

try added this property as max value but still users are running with some random values less than 5

`spark.cores.max 5`